# Best way to read a text file with different types of values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how to read a text file in Python that contains some information in date, time, name, binary, and float values.

Here are part of the text file:

```
19-03-15, 16:00:00, Tom@gmail.com, 0, 26.94
15-01-01, 17:42:50, Emily@gmail.com, 1, 27.73
00-03-24, 16:10:06, Tom@univ.edu, 0, 26.9
16-05-15, 06:59:23, Alex@yahoo.com, 0, Missing_value
01-12-31, 23:01:00, Sophia@gmail.com, 1, 27.1666
```

I am going to use this information later as a dataset for building a machine learning model.

Comment: That kind of file is called csv (comma separated values). Check out the built-in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or you can use [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: What type of data is your machine learning model accepting as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely you need pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt',sep=', ',headers=yourcolumns)
```